# sonarqube quality gate - fail on 'unsupported language'

Tags: sonarqube

New to sonarqube quality gates. Asking for some help -

Is there way to have a quality gate fail based on, and I'll use the business term, 'unsupported language' - which may be defined as anything that doesn't have a sonarqube scanner....or more specifically defined by a business stance of no more language 'XYZ'.

Applied:
Is there a way to fail quality gate, at least at a high level, by detecting the existence of, say for example, files by extension (i.e. .groovy for groovy files, .c/.h for C++ files for example, .bsh for beanshell scripts for example), and then to provide a simple 'linecount' showing how many files and how many lines are in the files that are 'out of compliance'?

p.s. linecount is show 'scope', so if filesize is easier, that would work at a high level, although linecount is easier to reason/guesstimate with.

p.p.s Additional reasoning/complication - 'code coverage' metrics are only based on recognized scans, so a project showing '95% code coverage' for only 2 java files, but the other 40 groovy files, for example, are not included in the metric.  This example will help apply more understanding as to why looking for ways to address this (other than adding an unsupported groovy sonar plugin, which I see/know about, but is not the root problem).

Thanks for any creative/quick-to-apply options!

-Darren